# Why is the first letter of the char array being cut off during this ssl write procedure?

Tags: c++, c, vb.net, sockets, ssl

I am using TCP sockets in c and sending data across the network to another machine encrypted using SSL. However, for some reason that I cannot seem to figure out, the first letter of the sentence being written to the socket is cut off.

The server side program is writing the data to the socket with the line:

```
err = SSL_write (ssl, "This is a message", strlen("This is a message"));
```

and the following function on the client is used to retrieve the data from the socket (vb.net):

```
Public Function TCPRead(ByVal SecureSocket As SslStream)
Dim bytes(SecureSocket.ReadByte) As Byte

 SecureSocket.Read(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Count)

Return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Bytes)
End Function
```

However, the string returned from the socket on the client side is:

> his is a message

The manual for ssl_write (https://linux.die.net/man/3/ssl_write) says that:

> SSL_write() writes num bytes from the buffer buf into the specified ssl connection.

So surely the above C code above writes the chars from the sentence above equal to that of the amount of letters in the char array?

I'm worried that this might be something really stupid that I can't see.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My basic is weak, but I've a bad feeling you're consuming the first byte in the message here: `Dim bytes(SecureSocket.ReadByte) As Byte`, trying to use it as the size of the message.

C and C++ don't advertise string length in the first byte. They mark the end of the string with a null character. `strlen` computes the length of the string by reading and counting until it finds the null character.

If you want to prepend the length, you'll have to do something like

```
const char* msg = "This is a message";
uint8_t len = strlen(msg); // note: this will fail hilariously 
                           // if the string is greater than 255 characters
SSL_write (ssl, &len, sizeof(len)); // note - totally ignoring errors here
SSL_write (ssl, msg, len);
```

If C++ is on the table, and it's been tagged so it better be,

```
std::string str = "This is a message";
uint8_t len = str.length(); // note: this will fail hilariously if the string 
                            // is greater than 255 characters long
SSL_write (ssl, &len, sizeof(len)); // note - totally ignoring errors here
SSL_write (ssl, str.c_str(), len);
```

Comment: You were correct about the issue with the client side code. New code is: `Dim bytes(TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte` and it works as intended.

Comment: @Xeenenta a warning: TCP is a stream, not packet based. When you get alerted to data arrival you may not have all of the message you sent and you may have multiple messages queued up. If you don't care, this is easy. Carry on. If you do care, you will need some mechanism to know when you have a complete message so you don't hand half a message (or ten messages) off to the handler.

Comment: Thanks Remy. Don't know why I went signed there.